# Time complexity for concatenating strings

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, big-o-notation

I was going through this piece of code from an algorithms books and something doesn't look clear

[image: concatenating strings]

Please ignore the spelling errors,

How does 0(x + 2x + nx) reduce to o(xn^2) ?

My analogy, assuming x is a constant 1 and n is 2
(x + 2x) == 3 assuming x is a constant 1

From the book
(x2^2) == 4 assuming x is a constant 1

Am i right ?

Comment: As others have mentioned, the book claimed $O(x + 2x + ... + nx)$ complexity, which is different than $O(x + 2x + nx)$. However, your analogy might point out another misunderstanding. Could you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish with it?

Answer (score 1):

> How does O(x + 2x + nx) reduce to O(xn^2) ?

`O(x + 2x + nx)` will be reduced to `o(xn)`. But as your text says `O(x + 2x + ... + nx)` will be reduced to `o(xn^2)`. (So if you have `n = 5` for example you have the time complexity `O(1x + 2x + 3x + 4x + 5x)` which is equal to `O(15x)`.) The time complexity of `1 + 2 + ... + n` is `O(n^2)` (since `1 + 2 + ... + n = (n^2+n)/2`, see my comment below). But in your case every addend in the sum must be multiplied with `x`, so you have `O(x*n^2)` as final result.

Comment: The expression $1+2+\dots+n$ doesn’t have any time complexity. Rather, you’re interested in its asymptotic rate of growth.

Comment: Maybe it is couched imprecisely, sorry. Back to the joinWords-function from the question:
If you copy 1 character, then copy 2 characters ... and in the end copy n characters then you have `(n^2+n)/2` copy-steps which describes the time complexity of the joinWords-function here.

Answer (score 1):

The author did not say

$$x+2x+\cdots+nx=n^2x.$$

He said

$$x+2x+\cdots+nx=\frac{n(n+1)}2x$$ so that

$$x+2x+\cdots+nx=O(n^2x).$$

If you don't know the meaning of the asymptotic notation $O$, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation.

Notice that $1+2=\dfrac{2\cdot(2+1)}2$ is quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Here, Big $ O $ notation refers to the asymptotic upper bound to the running time as a function of input length. A formal definition and reference can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-algorithms-big-o-analysis/). 
As $ n^2 $ is a satisfactory upper bound to the function $ \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $ , the running time which comes out as $ \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $ can be expressed as $ O(n^2) $

Answer (score -1):

We can't say what the time complexity is, because it depends on the implementation. There is no good reason why making a copy of a string with n characters should take O(n), and not O(1). Actually, implementors of standard libraries and languages will work hard to make sure the time is O(1).

I would be reasonably sure that equivalent code in Swift would run in O (xn). At least if we replace "sentence = sentence + w" with "sentence.append(w)", and a clever compiler can do that.